# Make Kotlin Serializer work with Retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, serialization, retrofit, kotlin-android-extensions

I cant make Kotlin Serializer work with Retrofit. I am using `com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-kotlinx-serialization-converter:0.5.0` package along with Retrofit.

### data classes

```
import kotlinx.serialization.SerialName
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable


@Serializable
data class YelpSearchResult(
    @SerialName("total") val total: Int,
    @SerialName("businesses") val restaurants: List<YelpRestaurant>
)

data class YelpRestaurant(
    val name: String,
    val rating: Double,
    val price: String,
    @SerialName("review_count") val numReviews: Int,
    @SerialName("distance") val distanceInMeters: Double,
    @SerialName("image_url") val imageUrl: String,
    val categories: List<YelpCategory>,
    val location: YelpLocation
) {

    fun displayDistance(): String {
        val milesPerMeter = 0.000621371
        val distanceInMiles = "%.2f".format(distanceInMeters * milesPerMeter)
        return "$distanceInMiles mi"
    }
}

data class YelpCategory(
    val title: String
)

data class YelpLocation(
    @SerialName("address1") val address: String
)
```

### service interface

```
public interface YelpService {
    @GET("businesses/search")
    fun searchRestaurants(
        @Header("Authorization") authHeader: String,
        @Query("term") searchTerm: String,
        @Query("location") location: String): Call<YelpSearchResult>
}
```

The Activity

```
    val contentType = MediaType.get("application/json")
    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(Json.asConverterFactory(contentType))
            .build()

    val yelpService = retrofit.create(YelpService::class.java)


    yelpService.searchRestaurants("Bearer ${api_key}",
        "Something", "Some Location").enqueue(
            object: Callback<YelpSearchResult> {
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<YelpSearchResult>, t: Throwable) {
                    Log.d("MainActivity", "err ${t}")

                }
                override fun onResponse(call: Call<YelpSearchResult>, response: Response<YelpSearchResult>) {
                    Log.d("MainActivity", "succ ${response}")
                }
            }
    )
```

When Running, the thrown exception is,

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.xx.xx/com.xx.xx.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create converter for
>   class com.xx.xx.YelpSearchResult
>
> Unable to create converter for class com.xx.xx.YelpSearchResult
>           for method YelpService.searchRestaurants
>
> Caused by: kotlinx.serialization.SerializationException: Can't locate
>   argument-less serializer for class YelpSearchResult. For generic
>   classes, such as lists, please provide serializer explicitly.

What am I doing wrong? thanks for any directions.

Comment: why you not use `Parcelize`?

Comment: It is weird to use a serializable or parcelable data class to fetch the api result, it is not a good practice because breaks any clean architecture principle.  So, my advice it is to create two data class, one to fetch the api result and another to populate your view, so you only needs a mapper: fun map(yourApiResult: DataClassApi): DataClassUI

Comment: please check this issue https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/issues/337 and the solution https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/custom_serializers.md

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You forgot to put `@Serializable` annotation on top of `YelpRestaurant`

```
@Serializable
data class YelpRestaurant {
...
}
```

`YellCategory` and `YelpLocation` should also have the annotation at place.

Answer (score 1):

Add Serializable in your data classes

```
import kotlinx.serialization.SerialName
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable


@Serializable
data class YelpSearchResult(
    @SerialName("total") val total: Int,
    @SerialName("businesses") val restaurants: List<YelpRestaurant>
)

@Serializable
data class YelpRestaurant(
    val name: String,
    val rating: Double,
    val price: String,
    @SerialName("review_count") val numReviews: Int,
    @SerialName("distance") val distanceInMeters: Double,
    @SerialName("image_url") val imageUrl: String,
    val categories: List<YelpCategory>,
    val location: YelpLocation
) {

    fun displayDistance(): String {
        val milesPerMeter = 0.000621371
        val distanceInMiles = "%.2f".format(distanceInMeters * milesPerMeter)
        return "$distanceInMiles mi"
    }
}

@Serializable
data class YelpCategory(
    val title: String
)

@Serializable
data class YelpLocation(
    @SerialName("address1") val address: String
)
```